# How to use KeyListener for moving Rectangles

Tags: java

I am trying to move a rectangle while the key is pressed and to stop it on release like the game "Snake". As reference I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Km81XyczqC4&t=276s) tutorial.

I tried to adjust a few things in my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
    
    
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;    
    
public class f3 extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener { 
    
    static JFrame frame;
    static Timer t;
    static int x, y, velx, vely, c;
    
    f3(){
        
        t = new Timer(5, this);
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        velx = 0;
        vely = 0;
        
        frame = new JFrame();
        
        frame.addKeyListener(this);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        frame.setSize(500,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
    
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);
        
        t.start();
    }
        
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
        x = x + velx;
        y = y + vely;
        repaint();
    
    }
    
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        c = e.getKeyCode();
       
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            velx = 1;
            vely = 0;
        }
    
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            velx = -1;
            vely = 0;
        }
    
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            velx = 0;
            vely = -1;
        }
    
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            velx = 0;
            vely = 1;
    
        }
    }
    
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       new f3();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `velx` and `vely` are set after a key event is triggered. Since you are using a `Timer` here, the GUI will continuously update because `actionPerformed` is repeatedly triggered.

Remove the `Timer`, then put the change section of `keyPressed` to this form and you will get a desired result.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

   if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
      velx = 1;
      vely = 0;
      x = x + velx;
      y = y + vely;
      repaint();
   }     

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `velx` and `vely` indicate the velocity of the movement (as opposed to moving the player one space at a time, for instance), you will want to also ensure `keyReleased` returns the appropriate velocity to 0 when the specific key associated with that axis is released.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a handler for keyReleased method, where you should set velocities to zero as such:

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    velx = 0;
    vely = 0;
}
```